# How to make an association map containing white spaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an association map that matched a company with its loogo.
The purpose would be to show this logo on `google-map`.

I am completing the association map company <--> logo but I realized that the name of some vessels have a white space as shown below and I don't know how to correct that problem:

**the problem** I have is how do I make an association map with a white space? In this way I get a compilation error and don't know how to solve the problem:

Below a snippet of code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';

const shipCompanyMap = {
    VesselA: 'COMPANY-A',  //<-- No white space in 
    Vessel B: 'COMPANY-B',   // <-- white space
    Vessel C: 'COMPANY-C',    // <-- white space
    // Other companies...
};

const companyImageMap = {
    COMPANY-A: '../src/logos/company_A.jpg',
    COMPANY-B: '../src/logos/company_B.png',
    COMPANY-C: '../src/logos/company_C.png',
    // Other logos...
};

const associationMap = Object.values(shipCompanyMap).reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ({
        ...acc,
        [curr]: companyImageMap[curr]
    }),
    {}
);

const Ship = ({ ship }) => {
    const shipName = ship.NAME;
    const company = shipCompanyMap[shipName];
    const shipImage = companyImageMap[company] || defaultImg;
    return (
        <div>
            {/* Render shipImage image */}
            <img src={shipImage} alt="Logo" />
        </div>
    );
};
export { Ship };
```

**What I have done so far:**

1. I suspected that I had to treat it as an array and started working in that direction. But since I am not passing a "real" object but am trying to make an association map, working to pass the object was not a good way and I have some issues understanding how to treat white spaces.
2. I am not sure I have to [replace](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-replace-whitespace-javascript/) the white space. But I don't think so as the name of some vessels have a white space as shown above.
3. I came across the [trimming](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) function that seems to be doing something close, but I am not sure how to use it.

I have the impression that the white space should be sort of neglected (or trimmed) but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may quote your keys:

```
const shipCompanyMap = {
    "VesselA": 'COMPANY-A',  //<-- No white space in 
    "Vessel B": 'COMPANY-B',   // <-- white space
    "Vessel C": 'COMPANY-C',    // <-- white space
    // Other companies...
};
```

However in a real world scenario this may not be relevant any longer as you will probably load the data from a service via JSON anyhow.

I like to use sanitised/normalised keys, so i will replace any [^a-zA-Z0-9] characters with a "_", and i may be stripping out whitespaces altogether and also lowercasing all the characters. In most situations you can care less about the actual value for the purpose of a quick lookup. You may even be just using a hash of such a normalised value as key.